# XAML Code Snippet not rendering properly

Tags: c#, xaml, code-snippets

I'm trying to make a XAML #region snippet but for some reason its producing a bunch of weird results. Here is the snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <Header>
    <SnippetTypes>
      <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
    </SnippetTypes>
    <Title>Region</Title>
    <Author>A. Albert</Author>
    <Description>XAML snippet for a region</Description>
    <HelpUrl>
    </HelpUrl>
    <Shortcut>region</Shortcut>
  </Header>
  <Snippet>
    <Declarations>
      <Literal Editable="true">
        <ID>RegionName</ID>
        <ToolTip>Region Name</ToolTip>
        <Default>Region</Default>
      </Literal>
    </Declarations>
    <Code Language="XAML"><![CDATA[
    <!--#region $RegionName$ --> 
      $selected$
    <!--#endregion $RegionName$ -->]]></Code>
  </Snippet>
</CodeSnippet>
```

I would expect this to be the result:

```
<!--#region Region -->

<!--#endregion Region -->
```

but for some reason this is the output:

```
<!-- #region name -->

<!-- #endregion -->
```

This is particularly annoying as it puts a space between `<!--` and `#region` which means I have to backspace those out before XAML will recognise it as a region, for some reason it changes the default value from `Region` to `name`, and it skips the second `$RegionName$` altogether.

Any thoughts as to why this might be?